# How to populate a SelectBox with an array from Action class in Struts2?

Tags: java, html, jsp, drop-down-menu, struts2

I'm having a little problem populating a combo box with struts using the action class..

This is my form element:

```xml
<s:select label = "Estado" 
           name = "estados" 
          value = "#estados"
      headerKey = "-1"  
    headerValue = "---Seleccione---" 
           list = "estados"/>
```

And this is action class:

```
public class PrepararMedicosAction extends ActionSupport 
                                implements Preparable, ParameterAware{

    public List <Estado> estados;

    private IFachada lookupFachadaRemote() {
        try {
           Context c = new InitialContext();
           return (IFachada) c.lookup("java:global/Fachada/Fachada!com.interfaces.IFachada");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
           Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
           throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }

    public String display() {
        return NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        this.estados= fachada.getEstados();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2's Select attribute:

> `name`: the **source** object (the List in your case) containing the
>   data you want to show;
>
> `listKey`: the field used as **key** in the option element
>
> `listvalue`: the field used as **description** in the option element,
>   visibile on the combobox.
>
> `value`: the referred element to **preset the value**.

If `name` refers to a `List<String>`, you can use the `list` attribute to display the strings in both keys and values; if instead, as in your case, `name` refers to a `List<Object>`, you have to specify which attribute is the *key* and which is the *value*.

Example (let's translate "Estados" to "States"):

```
public class State {
    private Long id;
    private String stateName;

    // Getters and Setters here...
}
```

then expose a `List<State> states` through a `getStates()` method,

and your preferred state through `getMyPreferredState()` method.

In the jsp you will write:

```xml
<s:select name = "states" 
         value = "myPreferredState" 
       listKey = "id" 
     listValue = "stateName" 
     headerKey = "-1" 
   headerValue = "Please choose a state..." 
/>
```